# IE positioning div layout problems

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

I know this is not an uncommon problem, but my layout that works in all other browsers blows up completely in IE (8 and 9).

I don't know if protocol is to post all the code here or just a link...

it is: [www.megadyne.com/safezone/index.php](http://www.megadyne.com/safezone/index.php)

I think the relevant part is that I have a container div which is `position:relative` and then a bunch of divs inside that are position:absolute and the inner divs are being pushed out in IE.

There are lots of other problems with the layout—only in IE, but hopefully they are related?

Thanks in advance!

Brian

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the css for http://html5boilerplate.com/ it does a pretty good job standardizing all the css for browsers before you put in your code. Try using their css and putting @inline your css into their css where it asks for your custom css, and see if that fixes the issue.

if that doesn't work you can have a separate css file for IE with the HTML5 code

```
//If browser is IE version 8 or greater
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: That looks like an awesome tool that I am really glad to know about (boilerplate) but I just want to understand what different rules are for IE that are breaking the layout. (also I did fiddle with boilerplate--downloaded and tried putting my css inside theirs but it all broke down and I really want to avoid a complete rebuild of this page) Thanks!

Comment: HINT--> Discovered if I turn off position:absolute and overflow:hidden it sort of works... (but breaks in everything else) is overflow:hidden wonky in IE?

Comment: Everything is wonky in IE. your best bet is to use <!--[if gte IE 8]> <link to your IE compatible stylesheet><![endif]-->

Comment: Yea OK. I just now need to figure out how to fix it for IE. Right now, it isn't making logical sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was something wrong with my  declaration. Fixed that and all is right with the world again.